# Find source location of an aliased method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have:

```
# lib/freedom_patches/html_safe.rb
class String
  alias_method :dangerously_output_as_html, :html_safe
end
```

Searching the method name `dangerously_output_as_html` in the codebase works but wondering is there a programmatic way to find out where this alias is?

```
"".method(:dangerously_output_as_html).source_location
```

brought me to the `html_safe` location:

```
activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb
```

instead of where the monkey patch is:

```
lib/freedom_patches/html_safe.rb
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you defined the method dangerously_output_as_html?

Comment: @ElChapo It is defined by `alias_method`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a way to arrive at the location where `alias_method` is used to define a method; I believe that [under the hood at the C level](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/37994bc5322c02a21e8905d373bef802cac91f72/vm_method.c#L1556), they share the same internal representation of a method. My grasp of the C code is far from complete, so I could be mistaken.

Instead, you may way to use

```
def dangerously_output_as_html
  html_safe
end
```